# How to accept a pdf file from server in ember

Tags: pdf, ember.js

Consider the below URL:

> http://localhost:4200/abc/secured/rest/name/166

This URL returns a PDF file from the server. Code is done to successfully trigger the service URL and get the response code as 200.

What code should be written in ember to capture the PDF file and prompt a save as window to the User for saving the PDF file in local machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can try ember-pdfjs,

https://github.com/mysterlune/ember-pdfjs

And provide the URL as the `src` for the `pdf-document` which can be used to render the pdf inside a template.

In the same page you can provide a link like below which provide an `download` attribute (HTML5 attribute, not support by ledgacy browser)

```
<a href="/files/filename.pdf" download="file.pdf">Download Your File</a>
```

Code above will let the browser download the file instead of open it for viewing.

Answer (score 0):

execute this code in button click action handler.

```
 let link = document.createElement('a');
 link.href = 'http://localhost:4200/abc/secured/rest/name/166';
 link.target = '_blank';
 link.click();
```